# Unlocking weapon slots in Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

I have two "locked" weapon slots. How can I unlock them?

[image: locked weapon slots]

Are the accessory slots locked too? Do they have some sort of level requirement?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

They're obtained in parts of the main story; one in the early Sanctuary missions and one is unlocked :

> when you get back to Sactuary after it takes off. If I remember correctly.

The Relic/Class Mod/Grenade Mod/Shield slots are only locked during the tutorial, they're unlocked extremely early. You never have to do anything but complete story missions to unlock the slots.

Answer (score 1):

You get your first weapon slot upgrade upon finishing the mission where you get the message from Roland in Sanctuary.