# Unlocking all weapon slots for a lower level character after an existing character beats the game?

Tags: borderlands-2

I know when you normally unlock weapon slots as answered in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84839/unlocking-weapon-slots-in-borderlands-2), but mine's a little different. I have a few characters that have already beaten the entire game, or almost the entire game (right before the end of the final mission). If I create a new character, is there any way to unlock all his weapon slots without playing through to the point at which he gets all four weapon slots?

I ask this because I have a character that I've done this for, but I'm not positive how. It might have been because I was farming the Warrior and this character finished that mission, but I'm not sure.

edit:
Character A has finished the game on Normal and TVHM, and is on the very last mission right before calling the moonshot on UVHM. Character B is a newly created character. I started the game in UVHM with Character A, brought in Character B to call the moonshot, then saved on Character B. I *think* that's why all the weapon slots are unlocked on Character B, but I'm not positive.

Comment: @fbueckert The linked question is using a save editor, while this question asks how he HAS done this in-game.

Comment: Exactly -- or also how people have done it, not just me, assuming I haven't done something crazy with my game. :)

Comment: Are you saying that you've "unlocked all slots" for a character that has beaten the Warrior?

Comment: @OrcJMR Just edited to add exactly what's happened so far.

Comment: Did character B receive and complete the Talon of God quest, then? I'm not sure how jumping over main quests works, but it is possible the character just insta-completed all the questline, hence receiving Slot SDUs.

Comment: Yeah, I'm wondering if that's what happened, since character B did complete Talon of God -- but he didn't complete all the quests in between, to be clear.

Comment: Contrary to an earlier comment, the question, [How do I set my level, unlocked weapon equip slots and playthrough mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/111815/4797) doesn't specifically ask about using a save editor. Other non-save editor solutions are also welcome.